# Detect Registry changes

Tags: registry, trojan

Recently i found a trojan program running in my system, it copies some random name exe to my drives(except C:) and also copies random name exe to temp and which in turn asks firewall network connection request(from this i figured it's trojan)..also it changes the registry value for hidden files....

The main problem is that i can't find it in taskmanager...even checked all svchosts process location...im stuck!

So is there any way i can monitor particular registry key and know which program is modifying it...?
Thnx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at RegMon:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652